# How to use rotate 3D in a matlab figure without losing focus?

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

So basically, I'm using matlab to simulate several lines and points in a plot3 figure.

When I'm trying to navigate the result using then "pan" command, I want to focus on a particular part, but EACH time I try to rotate around the point I'm focusing, I lose the focus and it rotates around the center of the figure. Is there any way to keep the focus when switching between commands to rotate 3d?.

When I use zoom and then I use pan, I don't lose the focus.

When I use pan and then I use zoom, I don't lose the focus.

When I use pan and then rotate 3d, I lose the focus, and I rotate around the center of the plot/figure.

When I use zoom and pan and then rotate 3d, I lose the focus, and I rotate around the center of the plot/figure.

Is there something wrong with the rotate 3d command? Is there an option I can change?

Thank you!